# Chromedriver for linux32 does not exist - Python Selenium Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi, selenium-chromedriver

I'm creating a cross platform python script that executes some commands with selenium.
I have two questions:

1. How come the following script works on windows but doesn't work on Raspberry pi OS 32bit? The only way this works is to remove the webdriver-manager, but this requires
   manual installation of the webdriver.
   I'm using a raspberry pi 3

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.utils import ChromeType

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()), options=options)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
print(driver.title)
```

The output is:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/Software $ /bin/python /home/pi/Documents/Software/test.py


====== WebDriver manager ======
Current chromium version is 95.0.4638
Get LATEST chromedriver version for 95.0.4638 chromium
There is no [linux32] chromedriver for browser  in cache
Trying to download new driver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/95.0.4638.69/chromedriver_linux32.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Software/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()), options=options)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webdriver_manager/chrome.py", line 32, in install
    driver_path = self._get_driver_path(self.driver)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webdriver_manager/manager.py", line 30, in _get_driver_path
    file = download_file(driver.get_url(), driver.ssl_verify)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webdriver_manager/utils.py", line 98, in download_file
    validate_response(response)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/webdriver_manager/utils.py", line 80, in validate_response
    raise ValueError("There is no such driver by url {}".format(resp.url))
ValueError: There is no such driver by url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/95.0.4638.69/chromedriver_linux32.zip
```

2. How can I create a python script that uses selenium webdriver in **headless** mode and works on every platform? I mean, if I use chromewebdriver in the script, the user who will use the script must have chrome installed, as well as if a firefox the user must have firefox installed. Is there any webdriver that works without external script installations?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

The problem is not with the webdriver manager but the fact that chromedrivers for chromium do not exist for linux32. In fact at the address: "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/95.0.4638.69/chromedriver_linux32.zip" there is no chromedriver, but replacing linux32 with linux64 a package is downloaded but not compatible with linux32.
The thing I don't understand is if the chromedrivers for linux32 don't exist then why installing them with: "sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver" and then removing the webdriver-manager calls from the code, does the python script work? Then there are chromedrivers for linux32, only they are not present in the main chromedriver site.
I am using a raspberry pi 3 with chromium 95.0.4638.69.

Comment: 1) Try updating PIP on the rasberry.

Comment: 2) You could switch your code over to Java and use HTMLUnit.  Java has it's own run-time, and HTMLUnit can be easily packaged with your .jar file.  Otherwise you'd have to install specific browsers and your install file would be pretty large... (I made one package that included a Windows XP and forward compatible version of Chrome with webdrivers, selenium and program that was about 96MB.)

Comment: @pcalkins Hey, thanks for the advice, I tried to update pip but it was already the latest version and the script doesn't work. The problem would seem to be with the webdriver-manager not providing the webdriver.
However, I updated the code by removing log_level = 0 from line 10 so the output error is more detailed

Comment: when you use apt-get, what version of chromedriver is it installing?  In Windows you can just double-click on it and it'll show the version in console.  Or launch with chromedriver -v

Comment: webdriver-manager works perfectly on windows and linux64, because it finds the files to download. On Rpi 3 instead being linux32 raspberry pi os, there is no chrome and there are no chromedrivers for linux32 but there is chromium and with apt-get you can download the chromedrivers for chromium from the raspberry archives.
'http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/c/chromium-browser/chromium-chromedriver_95.0.4638.78-rpt6_armhf.deb'

The version of chromium on raspberry: 95.0.4638.78

Comment: Looks like those drivers are compiled by Raspian project team.  So webdrivermanager would have to point to the correct repo for that OS.  (Google doesn't make the 32-bit driver anymore...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. As there is no linux32 chromedriver developped by the official team (e.g. https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=99.0.4844.17/), you can't use webdriver_manager because it's looking at their repositories.

Yet a compatible chromedriver version is maintained by the Raspian team, so in order to make it works you need to :

- Install chromedriver for raspberry. e.g. for Linux:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
  ```
- When you instantiate your driver, you need to tell him where to find this chromedriver. Plus, you should also state that you use Chromium instead of Chrome (if so):

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

  options = Options()
  # browser is Chromium instead of Chrome
  options.BinaryLocation = "/usr/bin/chromium-browser"
  # we use custom chromedriver for raspberry
  driver_path = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(driver_path))
  ```
- Then you're good to go:

  ```
  driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
  ```

2. If you need a code that works for every platform, the best option I found so far is to distinguished raspberry pi from the other system:

   ```
   import platform       
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
   from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

   options = Options()
   # a few usefull options
   options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
   options.add_argument("start-maximized")
   options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
   options.add_argument("--headless") # if you want it headless

   if platform.system() == "Linux" and platform.machine() == "armv7l":  
       # if raspi
       options.BinaryLocation = ("/usr/bin/chromium-browser")
       service = Service("/usr/bin/chromedriver")
   else: # if not raspi and considering you're using Chrome
       service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())           

   driver = webdriver.Chrome(
       service=service,
       options=options
       )
   ```

Considering your question about not having to install Chrome manually to make Selenium works, you could probably install Chrome through a script to be sure that the user has it.
It will also work for a Docker use, e.g. for a DockerFile with a Linux amd64 environment:

```
   RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
   RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy instal
```